# Angular how to test subscription from EventEmitter in Component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I have the following subscription in my component:

`finishLanguageChange` is `EventEmitter` in one of my services

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Update dates on Language change
    this.refs.translateRef = 
      this.languageManagerService.finishLanguageChange.subscribe((event) => {
      this.langCode = this.languageManagerService.getLangCode();
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

and I would like to return the value for that subscription in order to test the code.

I try this, but unfortunately, it requires to return subscription type and I'm not sure what to do

```
  it('Check Date config', async(() => {
    spyOn(languageManagerService.finishLanguageChange, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(true);
     fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.langCode)..toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create mock spy object of the service.

```
let languageManagerServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<LanguageManagerService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = 
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // Provide spy dependency
    providers: [
      // other providers
      { provide: LanguageManagerService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('LanguageManagerService', ['finishLanguageChange', 'getLangCode'])}
    ]
  });

  // Inject spy dependency
  languageManagerServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(LanguageManagerService) as jasmine.SpyObj<LanguageManagerService>;
});
```

Test case:

```
it('Check Date config', () => {
    
  languageManagerServiceSpy.finishLanguageChange.and.returnValue(of("test"));
    languageManagerServiceSpy.getLangCode.and.returnValue("test");
     fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.langCode)..toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: languageManagerServiceSpy.finishLanguageChange.and.returnValue(of("test")); this does not work
Error is:
Property 'and' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<any>'